# How do I specify .constructor.name on a custom object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, instance, instanceof

This question must be rather simple indeed, but I cannot google or duckduckgo the answer, probably because 99% of beginner tutorials involve creating a `Person` object with a `name` property (which is unrelated to the constructor.name but pollutes the search results).

Instances of `Object` Objects can be detected using instance.constructor.name:

```
var foo = new Object;
foo.constructor.name; // "Object"
```

How do I set the constructor name on my own objects?

```
var Bar = function(){};
var baz = new Bar;
baz.constructor.name // "" <- Empty string
```

Comment: You could just test `if( baz.constructor === Bar )`, `.name` is not that reliable

Comment: True, +1, or similarly you can test `baz instanceof Bar`, but the reliability of .name is not a problem when you develop for only one javascript engine (e.g. `nodejs`). I prefer to know how this is supposed to work. nnnnnn answered this to the full extend of the question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of defining your constructor as a variable `Bar` that is set to an anonymous function, you can either do this:

```
function Bar() {}
```

Or this:

```
var Bar = function ConstructorNameHere() {};
```

Where the `ConstructorNameHere` name can actually be `Bar` again:

```
var Bar = function Bar() {};
```

(That should work in Chrome and FF, not sure but not very hopeful about IE.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the 'privacy' of the function played a role in the constructor name. Good answer. Accepted!

Comment: Not a problem, developing for V8 (Chromium/node.js).

Comment: Is there any way to make `ConstructorNameHere` dynamic? i.e to pass it as an argument for example.

Comment: @YuvalA. - you can use a class factory to do that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

**Important warning:**

If you use a JS minifier then the name will be likely optimized away and suddenly `constructor.name` becomes `n` instead of the object name you were expecting.

This can be especially hard to debug if it's only enabled in production.

Comment: This is fixed if you do `MyClass.name = 'MyClass'` or add a static name property: `static name = 'MyClass'` if you're using that feature. I found this to be more explicit, although boilerplate-y. Using the `static` property keeps it close to the class definition, and class names rarely change: `class MyClass { static name = 'MyClass' }`

Comment: Interesting solution. I’d be slightly scared to use it but it’s probably ok.

Comment: Agreed, though for me it was much less scary than having one value during dev and another value in prod builds.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to make an answer to consolidate things from answers and comments above.

The most deterministic way to have the class name work (especially after minification) is to set a `name` property on the class itself. **All of the following are equivalent**:

```
// option 1
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.name = 'MyClass'

// option 2
class MyClass {}
MyClass.name = 'MyClass'

// option 3 (preferred)
class MyClass {
  static name = 'MyClass'
}
```

If you want the class name to be dynamic, you create a factory:

```
function classFactory(className) {
    return class {
        static name = className;
    }
}

const MyClass = classFactory('MyClass')
```